# How to send javascript date object with POST request in REST CLIENT (vs code extension)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, vscode-extensions, rest-client

I want to make a post request using REST CLIENT extension in VS Code.

[image: Here's the screenshot]

How can I send javascript `new Date()` object or `moment()` or `dayjs()` objects with the request?

I tried changing `Content-type: application/javascript` but it didn't work. Please suggest some solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a plain text data-interchange format and it has no built-in date/time type.

You need to format the date as a string. ISO8601 is usually used:

```js
new Date().toISOString();
moment().toISOString();
dayjs().toISOString();
```

It should look like: `2023-01-20T12:17:00Z`.

Then the endpoint should parse it.